# .txtファイルに保存されているデータをdict型に変換する方法

Tags: python, python3

次の例のような，各数値がスペースで区切られているデータからなる.txtファイルがあります．

```
3 0.6 0.8 0.2
12 0.9 0.8 0.4
11 0.1 0.4 0.5
```

そして，最初の列の数値（この例では3,12,11）をkey，それ以降の数値をlistに変換してそのkeyに対応するvalueからなるdictionaryを作りたいです．

つまり，この例に対応する期待する出力は次の様になります．

```
{3:[0.6, 0.8, 0.2]，12: [0.9, 0.8, 0.4], 11: [0.1, 0.4, 0.5]}
```

やり方が思いつかないので，どなたか力を貸していただけないでしょうか．
よろしくお願いします．

Answer (score 3, accepted):

文字列のままで良いのなら、@payanecoさんの回答が正解だと思いますが、
期待する出力の提示内容を見ると、数値(keyがint、valueがfloatのlist)に見えるので、こんな感じになるのでは？

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [l.split() for l in f.read().splitlines()]

d = {}
for x in data:
    k = int(x[0])
    v = [float(s) for s in x[1:]]
    d[k] = v
```

Answer (score 2):

`split`を使用してスペースごとに項目を区切り、スライスすることで最初の項目`[0]`をキーに、それ以降すべて`[1:]`を値にした辞書を作ることができます。

```
s = """3 0.6 0.8 0.2
12 0.9 0.8 0.4
11 0.1 0.4 0.5""" 
# スペース区切りの配列をスライスしてキーと値に分ける
d = { l.split(" ")[0] : l.split(" ")[1:] for l in s.split("\n") }
print(d)
# {'3': ['0.6', '0.8', '0.2'], '12': ['0.9', '0.8', '0.4'], '11': ['0.1', '0.4', '0.5']}
```

Answer (score 2):

別解として(Pandas を使う場合)。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data.txt', header=None, sep=r'\s', engine='python', index_col=0)
dic = df.T.to_dict('list')

print(dic)

#
{3: [0.6, 0.8, 0.2], 12: [0.9, 0.8, 0.4], 11: [0.1, 0.4, 0.5]}
```